# Quiz questions in Linear Algebra i need help in

Tags: linear-algebra

While solving quiz questions of senior year in Linear Algebra I need help in solving these questions.

Questions:( They are true/false questions)
(1) For any n$\geq$ 2 there is an n×n matrix A with real entries such that $A^{2}$ = A and trace(A) =n+1.

I chose matrix A ( 2×2 case ) by writing $a_{11} $ = a, $ a_{12}$  = b,$a_{21} $ = c, $ a_{22}$=d  and then I obtained a contradiction in terms of trace(A) by writing $A^{2} $ = A and comparing both sides.

> But how to be sure that this holds for all n>2.

(2) There is 2× 2 real matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^{2} $ +1 .

I followed same approach by assuming that such a 2× 2 matrix exists and then trying to obtain a contradiction .

But in this case condition ocurrs on b, c which is bc= -5/4 which is true for b, c belonging to $\mathbb{R} $ but neither b=-5/4 , c=1 or b=-5/8 , c=2 satisfies.

So, I am a bit spectical.

Kindly give some advice.

Comment: for the first, try to prove that whenever $A^2=A$, you have $Tr(A)\le n$

Comment: for the second question, do you know what a companion matrix is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^2=A$, then the eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^2=\lambda$, so they can only be $0$ or $1$. Then $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is at most $n$. Equivalently, look at the Jordan form.

For 2, try
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$